# Python: Slice/Cut 3 arrays for a given value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 lists from type float64. I want to cut the list1, if a given value is occured in list1. For this given value, i want to find the index in list1 and to cut the list2,list3 also (after this index). What i made:

```
list1 = array([1.99, 3.34, 5.3, 6.121, 7.5, 9.001, 8.1011, 9.089])

list2 = array([15.09, 14.112, 11.09, 9.01, 7, 3.21, 2, 1])

list3 = array([1.5, 3, 5.4, 6.2, 7.5, 9, 10.3, 11.5])

for i,v in enumerate(list1):
    if v> 6.121 in list1:
        list1 = list1[0:i]
        list2 = list2[0:i]
        list3 = list3[0:i]

print list1,list2,list3
```

This code only works, if the given value is existing in list1.
I want to get:

if value `v > 7` in `list1`, is `index=4`, so cut `list1,list2,list3` after index 3.

Output should be:

```
    list1 = array([1.99, 3.34, 5.3, 6.121])

    list2 = array([15.09, 14.112, 11.09, 9.01])

    list3 = array([1.5, 3, 5.4, 6.2])
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: i have already been used bisect. list1[:bisect.bisect_right(list1,7)] But i dont know, how i can get the index, and then cut the list2,list3..

Comment: yes, it' true! If i write if v > 6.121:, then it works! But not for my real lists, they have the same type :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you're using numpy:

```
list1 = list1[list1 <= 6.121]
sli = len(list1)
list2 = list2[:sli]
list3 = list3[:sli]

print list1,list2,list3
[ 1.99   3.34   5.3    6.121] [ 15.09   14.112  11.09    9.01 ] [ 1.5  3.   5.4  6.2]
```

As your arrays are not sorted you could use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile
value = 6.121
sli = len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x <= value,list1)))
list1 =list1[:sli]
list2 = list2[:sli]
list3 = list3[:sli]

print list1,list2,list3
[ 1.99   3.34   5.3    6.121] [ 15.09   14.112  11.09    9.01 ] [ 1.5  3.   5.4  6.2]
```

Comment: hey Padraic! Can you answer me one more question?

Comment: Sure. What is the problem?

Comment: I will have a look when I get back in my computer.

Comment: now I've 3 lists like:

`list1 = [ [11,22,33,33,44,550], [11,22,33,33,44,55], [11,22,33,331,44,55] ]`
`list2 = [ [10,20,330,43,45,57], [11,20,33,33,44,55], [11,22,33,30,44,55] ]`
`list3 = [ [101,22,33,33,44,55], [11,22,30,33,44,55], [11,22,33,33,40,55] ]`

I want to cut the list1, if a given value is occured in list1. For this given value, i want to find the index in list1 and to cut the list2,list3.

The code above from you is working only for arrays. Thank you very much for any idea, suggestion!

Comment: @lara, what code were you using the numpy or the takewhile?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I was using the numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close, but

```
if v > 6.121 in list1:
```

doesn't really make sense, and you should `break` once you've found the index to slice to. A demo with simple lists:

```
>>> list1 = [1.99, 3.34, 5.3, 6.121, 7.5, 9.001, 8.1011, 9.089]
>>> list2 = [15.09, 14.112, 11.09, 9.01, 7, 3.21, 2, 1]
>>> list3 = [1.5, 3, 5.4, 6.2, 7.5, 9, 10.3, 11.5]
>>> for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    if v > 7:
        list1 = list1[0:i]
        list2 = list2[0:i]
        list3 = list3[0:i]
        break


>>> list1
[1.99, 3.34, 5.3, 6.121]
>>> list2
[15.09, 14.112, 11.09, 9.01]
>>> list3
[1.5, 3, 5.4, 6.2]
```

Comment: yes, you're right... but it doesnt work for my real lists. They have the same type, not the same size.. what can you guess,what can be wrong?

Comment: @lara what do you mean *"doesn't work"*? Errors? Unexpected outputs? This works for me on both `list` and `numpy.array`.

Comment: @jonrshape: depending on the given value i either get empty arrays or full arrays, i havent any idea, why it doesn't work with the real values... But i used the method from Padraic Cunningham above and it works :) thank you jon!

Answer (score 0):

Different approach to solve the problem would be:

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x <= 6.121]
length = len(list1)
list2 = list2[:length]
list3 = list3[:length]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's array?

Anyway:

```
condition = lambda n: n > 7
if condition(max(list1)):
  list1 = filter(condition, list1)
  list2 = filter(condition, list2)
  list3 = filter(condition, list3)
```

Or more generic in a function:

```
def trimArray(threshold, *lists):
    condition = lambda n: n > threshold
    if len(lists) > 0 and condition(max(lists[0])):
        for l in lists:
            l[:] = filter(condition, l)
```

Answer (score 0):

@lara list1,list2 and list3 are numpy array and not list :).try this:

```
for i,v in enumerate(list1):
    if v > 7:
        list1 = list1[0:i]
        if len(list2) > i:
            list2 = list2[0:i]
        if len(list3) > i:
            list3 = list3[0:i]
        break
```

Comment: yes, they are all numpy array.. i got all of them from a list, so i forgot to rewrite ;)